# Acces json object from twitter api with GET request in javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

This is probably really easy but I can't seem to acces the data that is return when using a get request. This is my code:

```
OAuth.initialize('myappkey');
OAuth.popup('twitter')
.done(function(result) 
{
   var a = result.get('/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?count=2&since_id=14927799');
   console.log(a);
   console.log(a.status); // won't work
});
```

The console output is as follows:

```
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already got it!

```
    OAuth.initialize('8FKCUMR8CIy3E_PCYEhwZ0MT49U');
    OAuth.popup('twitter')
    .done( function(result) 
    {
        result.get('/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json?count=2&since_id=14927799').done(function(data) {
        console.log(data[0].text);
        });
    });
```

So after the 'get' I added .done() and in there it is possible to acces what is inside the object.